# How would I install SDL for use with VS 2010 (C++)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, installation, sdl

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on my Windows 7 partitio, and I would like to know how to set up SDL so that I can use it.

Comment: This? http://zakimirza.wordpress.com/2007/03/04/setting-up-sdl-opengl-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 3):

The folowing tutorials will help you for Visual Studio 2010, [Lazy Foo' Production](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php).

Also, there are multiple SDL tutorials that could be found at [SDL Tutorial basics](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics).